# Different side menu on each page

Tags: menus, pages, sidebar

Does anyone have a solution how to have different side menus on different pages?
Do I need to create template for every page? 
I've registered many nav_menus in functions.php and than used pages ID as a switch/case parameter. It doesn't solve anything if someone gonna create couple new pages and I didn't add ID's to my file...

As you can see english is not my first language but I hope it was all understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I know I shouldn't post under my post but I found a solution, I'm gonna start using plugin Page Menus Widgets.
It's bad I didn't think about using widgets for this earlier...